# Matching more than once on the same option creates too many mutable references to self

Tags: rust, immutability

This is sort of a conceptual question, but this code does not compile:

```
struct HashHolder{
    pub thing: HashMap<usize, usize>,
}
impl HashHolder {
    fn insert(&mut self, item: &usize) {
        let test = self.thing.get(item).clone(); // immutable borrow occurs here
        for i in 0..10 {
            match test { // immutable borrow later used here
                Some(t) => {
                    //nothing
                },
                None => {
                    self.thing.insert(0, item.clone()); // mutable borrow occurs here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives "error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.thing` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable", and highlights the lines shown above.

However, if I take out the `for` loop, it compiles just fine! It feels to me like this should compile without issue either way: the scope of the `match` ends within each iteration of the loop, so all the references should be "fresh". The same error can be produced if I remove the loop and just copy-paste the `match` block a second time.

My understanding of the referencing/borrowing is:

1. `self` is immutably borrowed `self.thing.get(item)`. But after the `clone()`, it should release that borrow?
2. `self` is mutably borrowed at `self.thing.insert(...);` but once `insert` finishes execution, that borrow should also be released.

So I don't understand why this error occurs. Moreover, the lines the compiler highlights are useless, since those three lines, *without the for loop*, are completely fine!

Is there anything I'm wrong about in my understanding of what's happening in this code, and what would be a better structure if I want to match multiple times?

Part of the reason for this approach is that in my actual project, the value of `test` will vary through the loop and can be given a value in certain cases, so the `match` might behave differently in different iterations. Maybe this isn't the best approach for the behaviour I want, but I'd still like to understand why it won't even compile.

Comment: `self.thing.get (item)` returns an `Option<&usize>` which borrows from from `self.thing`. After cloning, you still have an `Option<&usize>`. You probably want to `unwrap` it instead of cloning.

Comment: I don't think I want to `unwrap` because there are expected cases where `self.thing.get(item)` will be `None`. I'd still like to condition on `Some` or `None` after cloning.

Comment: Then you can use [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) to clone the item inside the `Option` and break the reference to `self.items`

Comment: Oh! So `clone()` created a new object of type `Option<&usize>`, and even though it was 
totally different than the original object, internally it still had a reference to part of `self`? That explains why I was wrong about point 1, and switching `clone` to `cloned` fixed the problem (and better reflects what I was trying to do). I'll accept that as an answer for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.thing.get(item)` returns a value of type `Option<&usize>` which holds a reference to `self.thing`. When you clone this value, you only clone the `Option` and you get another `Option<&usize>` which still holds a reference to `self.thing`. If you want to get an owned value, you need to clone the inner value with [`Option::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned) (or [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) since `usize` are `Copy`) which will give you an `Option<usize>`.